# Class creation memory load / anonymous classes

Tags: c#, anonymous-class

Working in an application and there's the following extension method listed for Exceptions:

```
public static void FillData(this Exception target, object data)
{
   if (target == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
   if (data == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

   string stackTraceSite = target.LastStackTraceSite();
   var stringDict = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();

   PropertyInfo[] pis = data.GetType().GetProperties();
   int pisLen = pis.Length;

   for (int i = 0; i < pisLen; i++)
   {
      string key = (stackTraceSite != null ? stackTraceSite + '.' : null) + pis[i].Name;
      try
      {
         target.Data[key] = pis[i].GetValue(data, null) ?? "null";
      }
      catch (ArgumentException ae)
      {
         target.Data[key] = "ARGUMENT EXCEPTION -> " + ae.Message;
      }
   }
}
```

This is then called or used in a similar fashion:

```
try
{
   // Perform some dangerous operation that throws an exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ex.FillData(new { CustId = 4, Category = "Foo", Style = "bar" });
   Logger.LogError(ex);
}
```

The members of the anonymous type (as in the example) are "reused" in some cases, but in many other cases they are quite different. (e.g. `new { FileType = Enum.FileType.RejectionLetter, FilePath = loadFilePath }`)

This sort of code is used in quite a few locations and in a web app that's going to get a lot of traffic.. one question I'm wondering is: will the definition of all those anonymous classes eventually bog down / crash / create a significant memory load even if / when they aren't being caught?

Comment: Are these properties static (that is, the anonymous types _all_ use some combination of `CustId`, `Category`, and `Style`) or is this just a lazy way to define arbitrary key/value pairs for each exception handler? EDIT: Also, I doubt _this_ would be the cause of your website bogdown/crash/significant memory load. These are happening in _exceptional_ cases. Do you expect your users to be causing these exceptions to be thrown left-right-and-centre?

Comment: Edited for clarification.. not the anonymous types use a numerous combination of things.. I have no idea how many. They appear to have reused them where possible (and thus re-using the anonymous class signature) but in other cases they're totally separate. I wouldn't think the exceptions would be thrown like crazy, but as I'm a contractor and at the moment quite know that answer. I wouldn't think that even ... 1000 extra class definitions would matter, but I was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set of property names is the same, then the type will be reused.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var test = new Test();
        var inner = test.Go();
        var anonObj = new { Name = "one" };
        Console.WriteLine(inner == anonObj.GetType()); // true
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Type Go()
    {
        var anonObj = new { Name = "one" };
        return anonObj.GetType();
    }
}
```

So you wouldn't run into problems from multiple calls with the same set of properties. But what about the definitions themselves? I wrote a quick experiment to see what would happen.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        new Test().Go();
        Console.WriteLine("End: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Go()
    {
        var anonObj = new { Name = "one" };
        Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    }
}
```

The memory usage was higher after the anon type was declared, even after all references are gone and garbage collected, so I am *assuming* that the type definition does stick around after a GC, and thus is around for the life of the AppDomain. So in theory, it could be a problem.

However, it will only create types for unique combinations of properties, so unless this is a *very* large codebase, it should cause no problems.

Erick

Comment: ..and that's if you actually instantiated / threw every Exception before the AppDomain was recycled, that's where you might have the issue, correct?

Comment: That's correct. It's only the set of property name combinations, as the values don't matter. Even if you have 10000 calls to this service, you still only get 10000 types.

Comment: While I knew about the "reusable anonymous" thing I guess my question was still "how many" - I'm going to accept your answer because of the memory test and the "_very_ large codebase" response. ;)